# Are black cabs responsible for nearly a fifth of central London's road transport Nitrogen Oxide emissions?

Tags: united-kingdom, pollution

Evening Standard reporter Ross Lydall penned this article on 4th April:

[Row erupts over black cab exemption to planned ultra low emission zone](http://www.standard.co.uk/news/transport/row-erupts-over-black-cab-exemption-to-planned-ultra-low-emission-zone-a3506996.html)

> “Londoners will, however, be astounded that the Mayor has exempted
>   black cabs from measures which apply to everyone else. This is
>   particularly surprising since ***Transport for London’s own figures show
>   black taxis are responsible for 18 per cent of road transport nitrogen
>   oxide emissions in central London.***”

Where does the highlighted statistic come from and is it accurate?

Comment: Title (pollution) doesn't match the claim ("nitrogen oxide emissions" specifically)

Comment: *All of London’s famous black cabs run on diesel* and *Diesel vehicles emit close to 40% of the capital’s emissions of both NOx and the particulate PM10* according to http://energydesk.greenpeace.org/2016/11/03/causes-londons-air-pollution/. This references http://www.ippr.org/publications/lethal-and-illegal-solving-londons-air-pollution-crisis but I don't have time now to follow up if this leads somewhere.

Comment: @user5341 changed it.  Giving up my search for more info.  #fakenews

Comment: I misread the title when I first saw it and for one brief moment thought it said "black cats" and this question seemed far stranger and more fascinating. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a TFL consultation document which is broadly in line with the figure 18% of road emissions in Central London.

https://consultations.tfl.gov.uk/environment/air-quality-consultation-phase-2/user_uploads/consultation-information-document.pdf

In 2013, road transport was responsible for 51%, with taxis accounting for 15% of that.

The projection for 2020 is for road transport to fall to 22% of the total, with taxis being 27% of that.